# Removing orphan JARs from IVY repository

Tags: java, ant, ivy

HOW to find orphan JARs from IVY repository, not used by my project.
Also, what is best way to remove them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The point of having the repository is to archive jars that are used by your project and any other. In order to determine what was "unused" you'd need to interrogate every project you have, build the transitive dependency matrix, and delete stuff not on it.

I use `rm` to remove unused stuff, but I also don't try to out-think my repository.

The quickest, easiest thing to do is to blow away the repository and repopulate it as you build your projects.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my question is How do you know, which are orphans JAR?

Comment: @MaulikShah I told you--find every single project that uses the repository and build up a dependency tree. There's no way Ivy can do that, because it doesn't keep track of your projects--it's the other way around. For example, see [this answer to essentially the same question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/109232/tools/Maven-Remove-unused-jars-repository). Updated answer with the only real solution.